# userdefined type in postgres as oracle

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5

Can anyone help me to implement the userdefined types in postgres?

how can i replicate the same functionality of below oracle types in postgres:

```
CREATE TYPE gr_data AS (
col1 numeric, col2 varchar(30)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE GT_DATA      IS TABLE OF GR_DATA;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE GT_TEXT      IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER ;  
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE GN_CPT       IS TABLE OF NUMBER        INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);
```

Postgres code is as below with type GT_CPT(NomTable) and GT_DATA().
can anyone explain why GT_DATA() type is used as a function here?

```
    create or replace function test() returns void as $body$
declare
NomTable text:= 'tab1';
tes text;
--Result text;-- not required
  lt_Result GT_DATA := GT_DATA();
begin
GT_CPT(NomTable) := tes;
--Result   GT_DATA := GT_DATA(); -- modified
     lt_Result.EXTEND;
     lt_Result(lt_Result.LAST) := lr_Result;
end $body$
;
```

Comment: `is table of` is usually done using [arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) in Postgres.  The syntax `Result   GT_DATA := GT_DATA();` is invalid for PL/pgSQL. I highly doubt you could successfully create that function

Comment: What is the declaration of the `gt_cpt` and `gt_data` variables?

Comment: GT_CPT         GN_CPT;
GT_DATA      IS TABLE OF GR_DATA;

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : i couldn't create the function as it is throwing me error for the improper type implementation

Comment: if `GT_CPT` is a "table of number", then assigning a string value to an entry makes no sense.

Comment: it would be better if you explained the underlying problem that you are trying to solve instead of trying to mimic Oracle implementations in Postgres. Very often a (completely) different approach is much more efficient when switching from one database system to another.

Answer (score 0):

`is table of` is usually done using [arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) in Postgres.

The equivalent to `INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30)` is probably a JSONB value (key/value pair) or a [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html) value. In both cases, you lose the type safety that `is table of number index by varchar` would offer.

It is very unclear to me what you are trying to achieve (especially how you want to use the `table of number`, but maybe the following will get you started:

```
create type gr_data as 
(
   col1 numeric, col2 varchar(30)
);

create or replace function test() 
   returns void as $body$
declare
  NomTable text:= 'tab1';
  tes text := 'some value';
  result gr_data[];
  gt_cpt jsonb := '{}'; 
begin
  -- this assigns 'some value' to the key 'tab1' in the jsonb key/value pair
  -- similar to GT_CPT(NomTable) := tes;
  gt_cpt := jsonb_set(gt_cpt, array[nomtable], tes);

  -- this assigns an empty array to the variable result
  -- if I remember correctly that's the same as Oracle's type constructor GT_DATA()
  result := array[];
end 
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: How about creating these below types in postgres ?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE GT_DATA      IS TABLE OF GR_DATA;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE GT_TEXT      IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER ;  
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE GN_CPT       IS TABLE OF NUMBER        INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);

Comment: @Sanjum: as I wrote: you don't need them. Use arrays (for `index by integer` types)  and JSONB (or hstore) for `index by varchar` types.

Comment: one more implemetation !! how can i use array in LPAD with type ? LPAD((tes - GT_CPT(NomTable))::text, 6, ' ')